# dat.gui load settings from external JSON?

Tags: javascript, json, user-interface, dat.gui

I have a webapp with a dat.gui interface, and I'd like people to be able to share their settings with each other. I know you can save presets to a localStorage file, or save them directly in the source as a JSON object. (http://workshop.chromeexperiments.com/examples/gui/#5--Saving-Values)

And I see in an older version of dat.gui there was a `saveURL()` function which I presume passed settings in a query string. (https://dat-gui.googlecode.com/git-history/v0.3.2/index.html)

Is it possible in the current version to either pass arbitrary JSON to the gui on pageload, or to specify a link to a JSON file, maybe through a query string?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've created an example (using dat.gui version 0.5) which demonstrates loading preset values from a JSON file on the initialisation of a dat.GUI object:

http://codepen.io/BenSmith/pen/lxiqb

The key part of the code which "re-hydrates" the dat.GUI object is this:

```
var json = '{ \
  "preset": "Default",\
  "closed": false,\
  "remembered": {\
    "Default": {\
      "0": {\
        "message": "Value from JSON",\
        "speed": 5,\
        "displayOutline": true,\
        "color1": [\
          128,\
          128,\
          128\
        ]\
      }\
    }\
  },\
  "folders": {}\
}';
  
  var text = new datGUI();
  var gui = new dat.GUI({ load: JSON.parse(json) });
```

Note how the "message" value (for example) has the value from the JSON (i.e. "Value from JSON") as opposed to the value in the default dat.GUI object (i.e. "dat.gui").

In practise you would obtain the JSON from a file instead of hard-coding it. Also note the use of `JSON.parse()` to convert the JSON string to a JSON object.